# How to configure Spring Boot Application to run on a specific database when launching

Tags: spring, selenium, spring-mvc, spring-boot, application.properties

I have a Spring MVC Application developed with Spring Boot. This is application is just for learning purposes, by the way.

By default, the app launches and uses a MySQL database. For unit and integration testing, I use an in-memory H2 database and it works perfectly.

So for that, I have two application.properties. One is under ***/src/main/resources/application.properties***.

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost/myDatabase
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = mysql

spring.thymeleaf.mode=LEGACYHTML5
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
```

The other application.properties in under ***/src/test/resources/application.properties***

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa
```

Now, I have to use Selenium for automated website testing and I don't want my MySQL database to be populated with test data.

I haven't done this previously in Spring, but I would like my application to work like this:

- Launch from terminal my application with certain commands specifying what database it should use. It should launch on localhost:8080
- And then, run all Selenium test in localhost:8080. All the data generated with Selenium tests is only kept in memory as long as the application is running

How to do this in a Spring Boot Application using an application.properties or other configuration?

Comment: What's the problem with this approach? When you are running your test cases, you can load application.properties from /src/test/resources/application.properties and it should work for you.

Comment: Have you read [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)? Just specify System properties when starting the application `java -Dspring.datasource.url=<your-test-db> -jar your.jar`. Or include profile specific property files and use `-Dspring.profiles.active=<your-test-profile>` before launching.

Comment: Put your database settings in application-mysql.properties and application-h2.properties and run your application with -Dspring.profiles.active=mysql(or h2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a separate properties file named `application-test.properties` and place it under `/src/test/resources`. The test database properties (or any other test specific properties) should go here.
2. On top of your test class, use this annotation `@ActiveProfiles("test")`.

   ```
   @ActiveProfiles("test")
   public class MyTest {
      ...
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Spring should do this for you automatically. To run application.properties from src/test/resources when you are running tests because spring runs with "test" profile. If not, add `@ActiveProfiles("test")` annotation on your test class (and by that I mean the class where you have your tests, not the class under test). If even that doesn't work, you can rename your src/test/resources/application.properties to src/test/resources/application-test.properties and select your profile in your run configuration (there is a field called 'profile'). [Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html) and [more info](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles).